# VueJs - How to set dynamic params with axios

Tags: post, dynamic, parameters, vuejs2, axios

I have a case like this

first i GET data from the server, then the response is

```
{
 data: {
   id: 4,
   status: A,
   items: {
     child: [
       {
         id: 28,
         product_id: 1
       },
       {
         id: 33,
         product_id: 4
       }
     ]
   }
 },
 status: 200,
 error: 0
}
```

after that, the data response I want to take the array items.child to be sent as parameters in POST.
and here is the format of params to set in POST :

```
item_id : data.id
item_status: data.status
item_combo_28_0: 1|0
item_combo_33_1: 4|1
```

item_combo is dynamic params get from response data

nb: item_combo_(child.id)_index : child.product_id | index

here my axios code

```
getData() {
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }
  let id = val
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: BASE_API('productcombo/' + id),
    headers: headers
  })
    .then(response => {
      this.itemCombo = []
      this.dataResponse = response.data.data
      this.setItemPackage()
      this.loading = false
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.loading = false
    })
},
setItemPackage() {
  if (this.dataResponse.items.child.length > 0) {
    this.dataResponse.items.child.map((row, idx) => {
      this.$set(row, 'item_combo_' + row.id + '_' + [idx], row.product_id + '|' + idx)
      this.itemCombo.push(row)
      console.log(this.itemCombo)
    })
  }
}
```

expected: How to set array variabel for (item_combo_?) to set in dynamic params of POST

here my POST code

```
sendData() {
  this.loadingPackage = true
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }
  let data = {
    item_id: this.dataResponse.id,
    item_tatus: this.dataResponse.status,

    ======= Here my expect =========
    item_combo_27_0: 13 | 0,
    item_combo_3_1: 15 | 0
    ================================
  }
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: BASE_API('openorder/additemcombo'),
    headers: headers,
    data: data
  })
    .then(response => {
      this.result = response.data
      }
      if (response.data.error) {
        this.$message({
          message: 'Error Network',
          type: 'error'
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.$notify({
        message: 'Error Connections',
        type: 'warning'
      })
    })
},
```

Comment: `expected: How to set array variabel for (item_combo_?) to set in dynamic params of POST`. could you give me an example according to that statement?

Comment: What is the result of your `console.log` in `setItemPackage`? Is that how you want it to be? When do you want to make your axios post request? It is difficult to understand what you already have accomplished and what still needs to be done.

Comment: @rafid i want to set params like this "item_combo_(child.id)_index : child.product_id | index" and here an example : "item_combo_28_0: 1|0"

Comment: @MatthiasS here my concole.log
{
 data: {
   id: 4,
   status: A,
   items: {
     child: [
       {
         id: 28,
         product_id: 1,
         item_combo_28_0: 1|0
       },
       {
         id: 33,
         product_id: 4,
         item_combo_33_1: 4|1
       }
     ]
   }
 },
 status: 200,
 error: 0
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but in your `setItemPackage` function you already have the code which transforms the `responseData` into your variables. So you only need to use that in your `sendData` function where you create the object that will be sent through axios.

```
sendData() {
  this.loadingPackage = true
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }
  let data = {
    item_id: this.dataResponse.id,
    item_tatus: this.dataResponse.status,
  }
  if (this.dataResponse.items.child.length > 0) {
    this.dataResponse.items.child.map((row, idx) => {
      data['item_combo_' + row.id + '_' + idx] = row.product_id + '|' + idx);
    })
  }
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: BASE_API('openorder/additemcombo'),
    headers: headers,
    data: data
  })....
```

Comment: @dede.brahma no problem :) please accept the answer then